# Change date format criteria query in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am displaying my test name and date by using below query. Now my date format is `2014-02-27 17:26:49.0` but i need to display in `2014-02-27` format. How can i modify my query for this?

```
Session ses = sessionFactory.getCurentSession();
Criteria c = ses.createCriteria(user.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", uid));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("name", uname));

ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
pl.add(Projections.property("testid"));
pl.add(Projections.property("date"));

c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(pl));
List<String> list = c.list();
```

Comment: use simpledataformat to convert, also how can u change 27 feb to 9 feb ??

Comment: My fault 27 feb. How can I use simpledataformat in criteria query. can you please give one example

Comment: kk i have added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
By using "sqlGroupProjection" I have changed my date format to **2014-02-27**

projectionList.add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date(date) as createdDate", "createdDate", new String[] { "createdDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is incorrect. It selects two fields, and you assume that it returns a `List<String>`. That is not possible. Every element of the list will be an Object array containing 2 elements: the testid, and the date. The date element will be of the same type as the date field in your entity (which, I hope, is `java.util.Date`).

So, to display the result of the query using a specific format, you would use something like the following:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
List<Object[]> rows = c/list();
for (Object[] row : rows) { 
    Date date = (Date) row[1];
    System.out.println(row[0] + " - " + df.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

    Date inputDate = new Date();

    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(inputDate));
}
```

output :

```
27/02/2014 07:25
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
        Date date = format1.parse("2014-02-27 17:26:49.00");
        System.out.println(format2.format(date));       

INPUT : 2014-02-27 17:26:49.00
OUTPUT : February 27,2014
```

Comment: But I need it in Criteria query